# The field items.Item.owner was declared with a lazy reference to 'items.user', but app 'items' doesn't provide model 'user'

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations, django-users

I have extended User Django model using `AbstractUser` and I have pointed `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'items.User'` in my  `settings/base.py`, then I repointed all the FK to 'items.User'( was User before the change), but I am getting this error in every class I have mentioned 'items.User' when I run  `python manage.py migrate`

Approach 1

```
======items/models.py=======
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
-----------------------------------------------
======core/settings/base.py=======
....
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'items.User'
....
-----------------------------------------------
=====contracts/models.py=======

class Contract(models.Model):
    .......
    owner = models.ForeignKey('items.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    .........
```

Approach 2
I have imported User model from core.settings.base.py

```
======core/settings/base.py=====
....
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'items.User'
....
-----------------------------------------------
=======contracts/model.py=====
from core.settings.base import AUTH_USER_MODEL
User = AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Contract(models.Model):
    .......
    owner = models.ForeignKey('items.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    .........
```

and still getting the same error, do I need to drop Db or something because I kind of start to think about a conflict with migrations file with the new change(kind of circulation-alike issue)!!???

Comment: Ypi have `items.user` (with lowercase) in your `Item` model...

Answer (score 0):

You used `'items.user'` (with lowercase) in your `Item` model (not the `Contact` model), hence the error: it should be `'items.User'` (with uppercase). But this is *not* how you should reference to a user. As the [*referencing the user model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) says, you should work with the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting, so:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Contract(models.Model):
    # …
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # …
```

You thus do *not* reference `core.settings.base` directly, but let Django's configuration model load the settings, convert it to an immutable object, and then use the [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) from that object. This will also fall back to the default for a given setting if you do not specify that setting.

You should do this for all models that reference the user model (so `Item` as well).

Comment: hi, I did 
from django.conf import settings   # in base.py
 owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)   # in contracts/models.py
and I am getting this error:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'Items.User' that has not been installed

Comment: @Yusuf: did you add `'items'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'items',
    'contracts',
]

Comment: @Yusuf: did you run `makemigrations`?

Comment: I have craeted items app, then  migrate, then I have added the User extentions

Comment: when I run `makemigrations` I get this error